# Modify R Shiny searchbar appearance and location in DataTables package

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, dt

Is it possible to move the search bar that is a part of the table in the R Shiny datatables to the front and center, as well as to modify the appearance of it? (i.e. add a search icon in it). Here is what I want it to ideally look like (with the search bar in the middle and on top):

[image]

For reference, here is an example of a standard DataTable in R Shiny:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can get an icon:

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  DTOutput("dtable")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  output[["dtable"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      head(iris, 5), 
      options = list(
        language = list(
          search = "<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-search'></i>"
        )
      )
    )    
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust elements with CSS

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  tags$style(HTML(".dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_filter {
                     float: left;
                     padding-left: 50px;}
                  .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_filter input{
                      width: 500px;}"
  )
  ),


  DTOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$table <- renderDT({

      datatable(
        head(iris),
        options = dom = '')
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: DT datatable()]